# how to implement checkbox selection of products in frontend using jquery or any other approach

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I am working on compare product functionality , and i want to compare product .My issue is that i want to implement compare product functionality like used in [this](https://www.cdw.com/search/?key=firewall&searchscope=all&sr=1) website (only frontend part) like the way it is showing selected product on compare template at the bottom of page and removes when ckecked on removed button.I need advice and steps if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad so break it down into steps and try to show your attempts.  The first bit, the ajax to send form data to the backend, would be something like:

```
$ (function () {
    $('#formId :checkbox').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/your-url/",
            data: $("#formId").serialize(),
            type : "GET",
            success : function(html) {
                console.log("success");
                do_something_on_success(html);
            }.bind(this),

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log("error");
            }.bind(this)
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks henry ,i work for same and implemented the ajax as u have suggested.Iam also getting data back but problem now iam getting is how to remove  that  product from product template below and uncheck the checkbox corresponding to it .Should i also use browser session to implement the functionality ,...